# How to manage Django reusable app templates that extend common base templates?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-apps

I have a project with some components that should probably be separated out into reusable apps. However, all of the templates extend a couple of base templates for the entire site. Should I include copies of the base template in each app's template directory? What is the best way to structure template directories/inheritance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the purposes of your app, `base.html` or whatever the base template is called, should contain the *entire* HTML document so that it can function on its own. If end-users want to override the template, they can add their own copy to `templates/yourappname/base.html` and do whatever they want inside that file, including extend their main site template.

Comment: So I would still have to duplicate templates across the multiple apps?

Comment: Huh? No. You can override it on a project-level by putting it in the main "templates" folder for the project.